# Need to validate GXT DateFields dateTo must be older than dateFrom

Tags: validation, date, gwt, gxt

Need to validate GXT DateFields dateTo must be older than dateFrom. As I'm thinking for solution to the problem it should be date Validator created for this purpose.

Any ideas, samples?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution to the problem is here:

```
@UiHandler("dateFrom")
void dateFromChange(ValueChangeEvent<Date> event){
    dateFrom.addValidator(new MaxDateValidator(dateTo.getValue()));
}
```

Answer (score -1):

this is exactly what u need

```
Date selectedFromDate = fromDateField.getDatePicker().getValue();
    Date selectedToDate = toDateField.getDatePicker().getValue();

    long fromDate = selectedFromDate.getTime();
    long toDate = selectedToDate.getTime();

    long diffGap = toDate - fromDate;
    long diffDays = diffGap / (24 * 60 * 60 * 1000);

if (fromDate > toDate) {
        Window.alert("To Date must be greater than From Date");
        return false;
    }
```

Comment: there's easier way for comparison: dateFrom.getValue().after(dateTo.getValue() and you haven't provided event handler and Window.alert() is not the solution - need to display the message in the validation error item.

Comment: you  did not mention that in your question and i have given out the most simple piece of code for it.